# background textview half screen

Tags: android

[image: screenshot]

I need set a textview (with its background) that fill half screen of device with fixed size of background. I try this code but I can't. The goal is: half screen, up I show image, down a textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/luna"
        android:textSize="15pt" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="jjkjkljkjkldjklsdfjkljklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklfjlsdfjkl"
            android:autoLink="web|email"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chiudi" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding weights.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/luna"
    android:textSize="15pt" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
               android:text="jjkjkljkjkldjklsdfjkljklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklfjlsdfjkl"
        android:autoLink="web|email"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button10"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Chiudi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you don't need a ScrollView here. because if the text in the TextView exceeds it's height, you can enable scrolling in textView

Comment: what is the picture resolution?

Comment: @PolHallen, it works fine! this is the correct answer.. 
and Asanka Senavirathna is right.. when the TextView exceed it's height, you can anabke scrolling in it

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

I have changed the inner linear layout to relative layout. I think it will give result as you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:autoLink="web|email"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="jjkjkljkjkldjklsdfjkljklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklsdfjklfjlsdfjkl"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/scrollView10"
            android:background="@drawable/luna"
            android:textSize="15pt" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chiudi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have defined scrollview first. And then I defined ImageView with match_parent sizes. So it takes up all remaining space of screen. This way, image proportion will also be proper. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Image again does not keep its proportions.

Comment: @PolHallen, Can you post the snapshot? Because it was working fine in mine.

Comment: I added the screenshot, like you see, the moon is not circle like should be. thanks